# Relable Icons in Software Application Dsiplay

Tags: shortcuts, rename

When I Click the Software Application  Icon the display shows 7 Icons with the label 'LibreOffic...'.
How can I change the lables to clearly show Writer, Draw, Calc, Math, ....
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install Menu Editor from the Software center. Select the LibreOffice calc from the left panel.
Name it as Calc or whatever you choose. Save the edit.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the names for those 7 as systemwide, use the path `/usr/local/share/applications/`

or per user base, use the path
`$HOME/.local/share/applications/`

copy the 7 .desktop files from `/usr/share/applications/` to any of the above paths as required.

```
$ ls /usr/share/applications/ | grep libre
libreoffice-base.desktop
libreoffice-calc.desktop
libreoffice-draw.desktop
libreoffice-impress.desktop
libreoffice-math.desktop
libreoffice-startcenter.desktop
libreoffice-writer.desktop
libreoffice-xsltfilter.desktop
$
```

Then from each .desktop files of those 7 you copied, edit the line `Name=`

logout and login

[image]